# Inserting into an XML using python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am writing a python code to insert a new subelement if ID is matched. I am trying to insert into a next line but but it happens to be adding in the same node where my ID is matched.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re
XMLFILE = "sample.xml"
mytree = ET.parse(XMLFILE)
myroot = mytree.getroot()
global update 
id = "C0"
for attr in myroot.iter():
    ver_name= attr
    if(ver_name.tag == 'name'):
        update=ver_name
    if(attr.tag == 'ID'):
            if(re.match(attr.text,id)):
                new_name = 'CAT'
                update.text= str(new_name)

                nm = ET.SubElement(attr, "name")
                nm.text="peris"
                mytree.write(XMLFILE)
```

Input xml:

```
<api nu ="F7">
          <name>CAT</name>
          <ID>C0</ID>         
</api>
```

Expected output:

```
<api nu ="F7">
          <name>CAT</name>
          <ID>C0</ID>
          <name>peris</name>
          
    </api>
```

Actual output:

```
<api nu ="F7">
          <name>CAT</name>
          <ID>C0<name>peris</name></ID>
          
    </api>
```

Any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the format of your input? Please also provide an example of input that you're trying to manipulate.

Comment: <api ="F7">
          <name>CAT</name>
          <ID>C0</ID>        
    </api>

Answer (score 0):

You’re adding a sub-element on (i.e. below) the `attr` element  so not sure why you’re surprised that the element is added below there.

For your XML you should simply use:

```
newel=ET.SubElement(myroot,”name”)`
```

In general if  were harder to find e.g. further down in the hierarchy, rather than using `iter` I’d use:

```
for api_el in ET.findall(myroot,‘.//api’):
    … do something with api_el
```

Or if you only want to check api with name inside it:

```
for api_el in ET.findall(myroot,‘.//api/name/..’):
    … do something with api_el
```

Definitely worth learning ElementTree xpath https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=xpath - start by getting findall working using just the first part of the xpath, e.g. ‘.//api’ and once you’ve got that working add the next part of the xpath e.g. ‘.//api/name’